# Where does class behaviour reside in EF Core Models

Tags: c#, .net, database, model-view-controller, ef-core-3.0

Maybe this is a very basic question, but I can't figure it out.
Let me explain:

I know from the MVC principle (I have used Laravel) that there are models and controllers (views are not the concern here). The models are the same as in EF Core, they represent the tables in the database, etc. Then we have the controllers where we implement CRUD functionality.

The question is where are am I supposed to write this CRUD like functionality, even if it's not crud logic. My gut says I just need to make another class that represents the controller of this model and specify there al the CRUD functionality, like reading, writing, etc. But I don't know if this idea is according to a convention, if there is any convention or best practice for this.

Where should I implement this?

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you’re creating a web API or similar and are storing your data in a database. Since you’re using the MVC pattern you already seem to have Models, and might likely need Controllers, let’s ignore Views at the moment.

Since you’re interested in where to create your CRUD logic I will use the web API scenario. You have a number of options depending on the application. You could implement a CQRS pattern and have separate classes for Commands, e.g. INSERTs and UPDATEs for the DB, and Query classes for retrieving data. You can do this with Entity Framework, Dapper or whatever else you prefer. The Repository Pattern is another option, if you do a Google search for that you’ll find plenty of Microsoft examples.

Within a Controller you could have 4 Actions: GetThing, PostThing; PutThing; DeleteThing. Note the naming convention here is HttpMethodEntity. From these actions you can validate data and call methods of your Data Layer to perform the CRUD actions.

Some topics to look into, from these You should start to understand the basics and how you *could* solve your problem.

1. Repository Pattern
2. NET Core Web APIs
3. CQRS
4. Dapper
5. Entity Framework

Comment: 1: Thanks for your comprehensive answer! Do I understand correctly that you are suggesting, like I did, to use seperate classes and interact with the EF Core models (which are classes too) through these seperate classes? The only difference is that you are suggesting to use a CQRS pattern instead of CRUD, right? It's not for a web API, I have not developed anything yet. Just thinking about how I should develop it. However I intend to use an external api in the application, if that makes a difference, I don't think so.

Comment: 2: So with this approach the EF Core Model is kindof encapsulated with the use of the CRUD/CQRS classes, I mean, you are interacting with the database/ef-core_model through these CRUD/CQRS classes, instead of interacting with the database/model directly in every single other place where you should use it. So with this approach you are reducing duplicate code aswell.